# Auto Matching with Game Center across two iOS apps

Tags: ios, game-center, multiplayer

We have two iOS apps a Free version and Paid version.  The only difference between these apps is that Free version as an IAP to fully unlock the content.

One of the modes in which the game can be played is multi-player over Game Center.  The Auto-Matching and Invite Friends works perfectly fine when someone tries to match Free App vs Free App or Paid app vs Paid app.

The problem however is, it does not ever find a Auto-Match when a user from Free app is logged in and another player of paid app is logged in.  This neither works in Sandbox nor in Production environments.

Other setup information:

- Both these apps are in the same game center group
- Both these apps have shared leader board and achievements (which is working fine)
- Both these apps have Multiplayer Compatibility correctly setup with each other in iTunes Connect.
- We had written to Apple Support about this problem but they came back saying Game Center is working fine and other setup in iTunesConnect also seems to be fine, they advised to check app code.

I have tried everything but nothing seems to be working.  Here is the code we have in our app to do the Game Center matching

```
GKMatchRequest *request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
request.minPlayers = 2;
request.maxPlayers = 2;
request.playersToInvite = nil; // This is not null only in case of friend invitations

GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc =
    [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request] autorelease];
mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;

[_presentingViewController presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Have also tried to set a value for `playerGroup` property of `GKMatchRequest` but didn't help

Questions:

- Is there a missing link in the code we are using because of which the Auto-Match doesn't work?
- Has anyone actually got this to work? If Yes, Could you please share some code samples and/or missing setup instructions?

Comment: Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated, any Game Center experts around?

Comment: Did anyone figure out the answer to this problem. I am experiencing exactly the same issue and do not see any solutions. The leaderboards and achievements are properly shared between the apps, but the two apps cannot find each other using the GKMatchmaker findMatchForRequest API - they do however find players using the same app without problem.

Comment: nope no help or respite on the issue.  We are still facing the same issue with our apps.

Comment: I am considering deleting the original app from the group and adding it back. Have you tried this? My logic is that the second app seems to have the right IDs for the achievements and leaderboards but the first one does not as it still reports the old achievement and leaderboard IDs without the grp. prefix. So my guess is that when the original app is added to the group in iTunes Connect, the transition is not done properly and the app is not really completely part of the group.

Comment: It turns out that deleting the first app that is added to a group is not possible therefore my proposed work around will not work.

Comment: Any follow-up? I got a similar case, but I want the behavior Tommy described (example: I want version 1.2 to never match with 1.1).

Comment: I have a new theory that I am working on. I noticed that the app prefix for the two apps was different. This was caused by the fact that the first app was created many years ago, before the prefix was a team identifier. I am now attempting to change the prefix of the old app to match the new app prefix - to do this, you have to contact Apple as only they can do it. Doing this will mean that if your app uses the keychain feature, your users will lose their settings - not great but workable if you plan in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't work. Game Groups are used to share Leaderboards but you can't create a match request to connect two different Apps. It even won't work with identcal apps, if the version information (version AND build) is not exactly the same. This is true for automatching but it also won't list online friends or nearby devices, that run a different version of the App.

Comment: According to apples documentation [here] (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/MatchmakingwithGameCenter/MatchmakingwithGameCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH12-SW14) it definitely says.  
  - *"When you create a new version of a game, you can declare whether the new version is compatible with the older versions"*.  
  - *"You can create distinct games (with different bundle identifiers) and still allow them to play against each other."*  So I am not so sure whether what you said is correct?

Comment: Moreover when we contacted Apple Support they did say its supposed to work in this use-case but there might be some issue with our code.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to this problem. It has to do with the app prefix of the two apps. If they have a different app prefix, it will NOT work. You can change your old app prefix to match your new app prefix by contacting Apple  https://developer.apple.com/contact/ .

You can read more here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2311/_index.html Once Apple completes the prefix change for the old app, they will start working without any code changes or even resubmission of the apps.

Comment: I checked, we have the same app prefix across our apps.  But it still doesn't match players across apps.